# Graph of a parabola

Tags: quadratics

[image]
The equation of the following graph is 
$-x^2-4x-c=y$ how to find c if 3OB=AO

Comment: What is your own attemps?  Say, when you put $x = 0$, $y = ?$

Comment: I think the parabola it's a graph of a quadratic function. What is it "graph of parabola"?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A(x_2,0)$ and $B(x_1,0).$

Thus, 
$$x_1x_2=c,$$
$$x_1+x_2=-4$$ and $$3x_1=-x_2,$$ which gives $$x_2=-6,$$ $$x_1=2$$ and $$c=-12.$$

Answer (score 1):

Finding the roots you get
$$-2\pm\sqrt{4-c}$$ then you know $$x_A=-2-\sqrt{4-c}$$$$x_B=-2+\sqrt{4-c}$$ 
then you need to have $x_B>0 \implies c<0$ 
so you need to solve $|x_A|=3x_B$
$$2+\sqrt{4-c}=3(-2+\sqrt{4-c})$$
that give you
$$c=-12$$

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation of previous answer:
$$y=-x^2-4x-c=-(x-A)(x-B)=-(x-(-3B))(x-B)=-x^2-2Bx+3B^2$$
Equating the coefficients:
$$-4=-2B \Rightarrow B=2; c=3B^2=12.$$